# Restoring Measure tool window in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, toolbar, measurements

My measure dialogue box seems to have taken leave of my QGIS. I've reviewed the previous answers about resetting the interface, checking for the dialogue box outside of view, all kinds of things.

The measure line does appear, but no measurement appears. Any suggestions on how to restore it?

Comment: I expected you have also tried `right mouse click over main panel > Toolbars > Attributes toolbars`, is not it? As well as `Settings > Options > Processing > Reset to defaults`?

Comment: Did you try to start with a new profile?  Settings->user profiles-> New profile...

Comment: The New Profile worked! Oh thank the lord (and eurojam) this was driving me nuts.